# How to parse a collection of unknown JSON object types inside a known JSON structure using JSON.Net?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am attempting to parse some JSON that has a known top level schema.  However inside the schema is one JSON object that can contain various types of JSON objects.

Example

```
{
  "knownfield1": data,
  "knownfield2": data,
  "knownfieldcollection":
    {
       "fieldofunknowntype1": "string data",
       "fieldofunknowntype2": 
         {
           "subunknownfield1": "string data",
           "subunknownfield1": null
         },
       "fieldofunknowntype3": null
    }
}
```

I would like to make an object that contains a mapping of the known fields, but can read the unknown fields in dynamically.  I was trying with Json.Net JToken and JObject, but I could not get it to work.  I kept getting recursive JToken exceptions.

Any pointers on this would be great.  Thank you.

Exception I am getting:

```
Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is a recursive collection data 
contract which is not supported. Consider modifying the definition of 
collection 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to remove references to itself.
```

--edit-- 
Mistyped Collection for object, fixed that.

Comment: Oops, my mistake on my typing. Let me fix that.

Comment: What is the problem with JObject ? You can parse your json string using  JObject.Parse.

Comment: I'm de-serializing the json into a C# object that has all the known fields defined.  But for the life of me, I can't get the "knownfieldcollection" (object) to de-serialize if I use a property inside the C# object.  I have tried `public JObject Field {get; set;}` and I get a recursion exception regarding JToken referencing itself.

Comment: To use a JObject you have to parse the whole Json string. Could it be a solution ? Anyway you have a dynamic object....

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am leaning towards, which will mean some refactoring, but hey, that's a developer's life right? =D heh

Comment: Would a JToken work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108451/discussion-between-thomas-and-thaldin).

Comment: I would love to if it weren't blocked by our work proxy.

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795045/accessing-all-items-in-the-jtoken-json-net

Comment: It looks like you are not actually using Json.NET to deserialize, you are using `DataContactJsonSerializer` and/or [tag:wcf].  See [Self Hosted WCF Rest service ERROR : Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is a recursive collection data contract which is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759607), [How to have a WCF DataContract with a json dynamic member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916865) and http://www.ikriv.com/blog/?p=1703.  Can you create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem showing how you deserialize your JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a winner.  DBC hit the nail on the head.  I had some left over WFC deserialization and it was causing problems.  As soon I made sure all the DataContract code was completely cleared out and replaced everything with proper JSON.Net tags and calls, it worked wonderfully.

Thank you everyone for the support.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question. Please edit in the pertinent details so that this answer can stand by itself.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for to be honest.   JSON.Net parses as expected when I replaced some left WFC DataContractJsonDeserializer code with JSON.Net parsing code.

As soon as I did, the JSON Object with the children of varying unknown types parsed into the object perfectly by simply using a Property of JObject type.